# Inserting records from TPT error tables to a relational table from ET1 and ET2

Tags: error-handling, teradata, informatica

I have a workflow which goes through a loop and load split files into TD table. I would like to direct the rows from the temporary tables created by TPT i.e, ET1 and ET2 to another table.

Here is detailed scenario:

1. I have a list of file names in a file (abc.txt). These file names are initialized in a loop and triggers workflow(indirect load) for each file.
2. I am using a shell script to trigger the workflow. However, I would like to keep track of the error records going to ET1 and ET2 tables to another table.
3. These records needs to be append for each file load with the corresponding file name.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dynamically created Insert/Select including the file name?

Comment: Right @dnoeth ...! I want to insert these records into a new table and keep on appending records for each run

Comment: As @dnoeth suggested, dynamically create an INSERT/SELECT with the filename to a log table or tables.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of handling such a scenario will be to have an additional flag in the text file with the file names. This flag can be updated as completed or processed after each successful run of the workflow.

To get the file name inside the mapping have the text file as a lookup inside the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

To include file name, just check the `Add Currently Processed Flat File Name Port` property on the Source Transformation.

Comment: Let me know if there's anything else you'd need. I didn't get p.2 from the question.